# How to prevent duplicate data appear in RecyclerView when pulling SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, android-livedata, swiperefreshlayout

I know this question is asked a lot of time, and I know the answer for the usual case, which is `arraylist.clear()` clear the `arraylist` before pulling the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. But in my case it seems a bit different, and I have absolutely no clue about it, so let me tell it step by step.

**What I want to do:**

I have a `RecyclerView` which normally only presents 1 type of data which is `List<Post> posts`. From here, this works perfectly fine. Now, I want to add the `NatvieAds` from Google Admobs to the first element of the `RecyclerView`.

**So here is my code setup:**

**PostFragment:**

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment implement .....{

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initializeRecyclerView();

        setUpSwipeRefreshLayout();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                postAdapter.removeAllStuff(); //Here clear all the item in post
                getPostInRoom(roomId);
            }
        });
    }

   private void initializeRecyclerView() {
       recyclerView = binding.postRecyclerView;
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
       postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
   }

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private void setUpSwipeRefreshLayout() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = binding.swipeRefreshLayout;
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                postAdapter.removeAllStuff(); //Here clear all the item in post
                getPostInRoom(roomId);
            }
        });
    }


    // I calling my own API in ViewModel and observe the LiveData returned.
    private void getPostInRoom(String roomId) {
        viewModel.getAllPostInRoom(roomId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Post> posts) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                if(posts != null && posts.size() > 0){
                    binding.postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    binding.emptyStateContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.unblockRoomButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    postAdapter.addAllPostToList(posts); // Here add all the arraylist item into the list in adapter
                    getNativeAdsFromAdmobForPostFragment(); // here called for Admobs 

                }else if(Objects.requireNonNull(posts).size() == 0){
                    binding.emptyStateContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    binding.postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

So as you can see, before `getPostInRoom()` is called in `SwipeRefreshLayout`, I already called for `postAdapter.removeAllStuff()` (for which I will attach the code below). So if I am not mistaken, the arraylist should be clear.

Here is the code in `PostFragment` to call to Admob for Ads

```
   //HERE CALLED TO GOOGLE ADMOB FOR THE ADS 
    private AdLoader adLoader;
    public void getNativeAdsFromAdmobForPostFragment(){


    NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
            .setAdChoicesPlacement(ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT)
            .build();

    adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.admob_test_ad))
            .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                    // Show the ad.

                    if(!adLoader.isLoading()){

                        postAdapter.addAdsToList(unifiedNativeAd); //here update the ads into the arraylist of the recyclerView
                    }
                }
            })
            .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                            + " load another.");
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {

                    }
                }
            })
            .withNativeAdOptions(adOptions)
            .build();

    adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
  }


}
```

**PostAdapater.java**

```
public class PostAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {  

    private static final int UNIFIED_ADS_VIEW  = 1;

    private static final int POST_ITEM_VIEW = 2;

    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItem = new ArrayList<>();

    public PostAdapter(PostAdapterListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void addAllPostToList(List<Post> posts){

        mRecyclerViewItem.addAll(posts); // Here add all the post into the mRecyclerViewItem
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAdsToList(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd){
        mRecyclerViewItem.add(0,unifiedNativeAd); // Here add the 1 nativeAds into the arrayList
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeAllStuff(){
        mRecyclerViewItem.clear(); // Here already called before `getPostInRoom()` in SwipeFreshLayout
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType (int position) {


        Object recyclerViewItem = mRecyclerViewItem.get(position);
        if (recyclerViewItem instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
            return UNIFIED_ADS_VIEW;
        }
        return POST_ITEM_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerViewItem.size();
    }

    ... all other code 

}
```

**What I have now:**

After all the code above,

1. When first loading `PostFragment`: the behavior is right which means that the ads appear on the first item of `recyclerView`, then the following is `post` that I fetch from server.
2. When I pull the `SwipeRefreshLayout`: the same `post` (which is 3 posts) duplicate and a new ads appear in the `RecyclerView`, every time I pull the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, another 3 same posts and 1 new ad are inserted to the `RecyclerView` again.

Which is means, the `mRecyclerViewItem` in `PostAdapater` is never `clear()`, but the new item is keep adding into the `ArrayList`, although I already `clear()` before I fetch the new item.

**Question:**

1. What am I doing wrong in the situation above?
2. What is the correct way to handle 2 types of `data` (`Post` and `UnifiedNativeAd` in my case) or 2 arraylist in 1 RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is built with the intention to **`recycle views`**. Everything in it is a separate process:

- Setting layoutManager
- Setting Adapter
- Defining ViewHolders

Even in **`Setting Adapter`** part, **`Adapter`** does not care **`what`** data is being passed, it only cares that **`data is there`**.

What I would suggest in your case would be instead of using **`ArrayList`**, use a **`Set`**. In a **`Set`**, you cannot duplicate the elements as that is its base criteria. Keep all the refreshing logic encapsulated in the **`ViewController`**, which in your case looks like a **`Fragment`**.

One thing i would like to point out is this function:

```
public void removeAllStuff(){
        mRecyclerViewItem.clear(); // Here already called before `getPostInRoom()` in SwipeFreshLayout
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This should be avoided as adding or removing a item in the **`DataSet`** should not require destroying everything in the **`RecyclerView`**, and then rebuilding it. You are actually hampering the main goal of **`RecyclerView`**, the **`recycling`** part. Rather make use of intelligent methods such as **`notifyItemChanged(position: Int)`**, which will notify the **`RecyclerView`** that only element at that location has changed, so no need to worry about other elements.

Comment: hey bro..what u mean by `using Set`? can u give me an example for that??

Comment: At the last part of ur question,do u mean that,when the ads is `arrived` ,then `notifyItemChanged(0)` (the first element in my case) after insert the ads into the `arraylist`?